# Can "as if you" be used without a verb?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-structure

I received a spam mail with the following text:

> That brief clip can not only show you the reality,
>   but it'll demonstrate how a large number of honest,
>   normal men **as if you** are fighting back again and
>   reclaiming their strength.

Is it possible to use *as if you* like this? Or is it just another example of bad language in spam?

I am missing a verb after it - *are fighting back again* belongs to *normal men* and not to *you*.

I would rather use

> normal men **as you** are fighting back again...

or

> normal men **like you** are fighting back again...

I understand the usage of **as if** in the context with a following verb, like

> You are stuffing yourself with the cake as if you had not eaten for three days.

Comment: As a native I instinctively know which of those is right & which is wrong [the spam is wrong, so is 'men as you'; the others are right] **but** I haven't the faintest idea **how** I know that. Looking forward to good answers.

Comment: Honestly, I couldn't make that call. I'm happy to see it here. If others are too, then all well & good.

Comment: As you surmise it's poorly worded advertising spam using **as if you** to mean **like you**. **As if you** belongs in different constructions such as: *Act as if you mean it*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spam is not grammatically correct. "As if" requires* a complete clause with a subjunctive verb. If the sentence continues after the "as if" construct, the subjunctive clause must be offset with commas.

*: There are exceptions, where you can elide certain words, but this doesn't fit the rule for that, which is as follows:

If the subject of the subjunctive clause is the same as that of the outer clause, *and* either the verb is a participle (e.g. "she was concentrating") or the clause is a copula-predicate construction (e.g. "he was tired"), *then* you may elide the subject and the copula (our examples might become "She was quiet, as if [she were] concentrating" and "he slumped, as if [he were] tired", respectively).